# How do I get the all values of a Custom Metadate Type record into a set?

Tags: apex, soql, custom-metadata

I have a custom metadata sObject - I want to retrieve all the field values into a set.

`Health_Cloud_Case_Integration_Settings__mdt cmdtRecords = [SELECT Id, Field1, Field2, etc FROM Health_Cloud_Case_Integration_Settings__mdt LIMIT 1];`

Please note that the query is dynamic, so might contain fields I don't necessarily know at compile time.

So I want the value of Field1, Field2, Field3 into a set. Sort of like getall().values() for settings?

Full code below:

```
String MDTQueryString = 'SELECT '+ String.join(new List<String>(integrationCaseFields), ', ') + ' FROM ' + 'Health_Cloud_Case_Integration_Settings__mdt LIMIT 1';

List<Health_Cloud_Case_Integration_Settings__mdt> cmdtRecords = database.query(MDTQueryString);

Health_Cloud_Case_Integration_Settings__mdt cmdtRecord = cmdtRecords[0];
// Set<String> fieldValues = cmdtRecord field values
```

Comment: Can you loop through the results of that query and add them to a set? More context on what you want to do with the resulting set might help.

Comment: Hi, it's a dynamic query so not sure if it would work. Updated OP with my full code

Comment: Do you mean to say you want all the values from all the fields in a single set, or all the values from each field in different sets, or all the records deduplicated in to a set?

Comment: @sfdcfox Option #1 please.

Comment: Derek's answer was correct, I just added a code example to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to make use of `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()` (method provided on SObjects, which is guess custom metadata types also fall under).

As the name suggests, the fields that you query get returned as a `Map<String, Object>`. From there, you could call `.values()` to get a `List<Object>`, and feed that into a set.

---

```
// Query records and strip out Id and audit fields //
List<Health_Cloud_Case_Integration_Settings__mdt> cmdtRecords = database.query(MDTQueryString).deepClone(false, false, false);
// A place to store the values //
Set<Object> values = new Set<Object>();
// Grab all populated values and put them in the Set //
for(sObject record: cmdtRecords) {
  values.addAll(record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().values());
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added a code example so as to not duplicate your answer.

Comment: Thank you both. Is it possible to return the values set as a set of string?

Comment: nevermind, I just looped through and done .toString(). Thanks again